# How can I use const_iterator correctly?

Tags: c++11, iterator, const-iterator

I am trying to make a container class with map from stl lib, but I have serious problem with `const_iterator`.

In my class `ConjuntoPreguntas` how you can appreciate, I have tried to use different format to `begin()` and `end()` methods, but I don't find the correct way.

In my main class I tried to use `imprimir` function, that receive `const ConjuntoPreguntas`, and there is the problem. So I need to use `const ConjuntoPreguntas&`.

```
void imprimir( const ConjuntoPreguntas& cp ){
    ConjuntoPreguntas::const_iterator it= cp.cbegin();


};

int main(){
     ConjuntoPreguntas CP;

    ifstream fin("PreguntasConstitucion.txt"); 

    fin >> CP;

    imprimir(CP);


}
class ConjuntoPreguntas{

    private:
        map<int,Pregunta> preguntas;

    public:
            class const_iterator; /
            class iterator{
             private:
              map<int,Pregunta>::const_iterator it;


           public:
               iterator & operator++(){
                ++it;
               }

               iterator & operator--(){
               --it;
               }

               pair<const int,Pregunta> &operator *(){
              return *it;
               }

               bool operator ==(const iterator &i){
              return i.it==it;
               }      

               bool operator !=(const iterator &i){
              return i.it!=it;
               }

               friend class ConjuntoPreguntas;
                 friend class const_iterator;
            };

            /**
             * @brief clase para iterar sobre la guia
             **/
            class const_iterator{
             private:
              map<int,Pregunta>::iterator it;
             public:

               const_iterator & operator++(){
                ++it;
               }

               const_iterator & operator--(){
               --it;
               }

               const pair<const int,Pregunta> &operator *(){
              return *it;
               }

               bool operator ==(const const_iterator &i){
              return i.it==it;
               }      

               bool operator !=(const const_iterator &i){
              return i.it!=it;
               }


               friend class ConjuntoPreguntas;

            };

            /**
             * @brief Inicializa un iterator al comienzo de la guia
             * */
           **iterator begin(){
                iterator i;
                i.it=preguntas.begin();
                return i;
            }

            const_iterator cbegin()const{
                const_iterator i ; 
                i.it = preguntas.begin();
                return i ;
            }
            /**
            const_iterator cbegin(){
                const_iterator i ; 
                i.it = preguntas.begin();
                return i ;
            }
            */
            /**
             * @brief Inicializa un iterator al final de la guia
             * */
           iterator end(){
                iterator i;
                i.it=preguntas.end();
                return i;
            } 

            const_iterator cend()const{
                const_iterator i;
                i.it= preguntas.end();
                return i;
            }
            /* const_iterator cend(){
                const_iterator i;
                i.it= preguntas.end();
                return i;
            }
             */**


};
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Not clear what is your problem and what is your intent. Normally, methods returning constant iterators are ``const``, like ``const_iterator begin()const{/*...*/}``. Also, constant iterator normally should return ``const pair<const int,Pregunta>&``, otherwise it's... well, not constant.

Comment: Ok, When I use   "const_iterator cbegin() const{ .........}"     and I try to compile that, the compilator said me error :                                        error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<int, Pregunta>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, Pregunta> >}’ and ‘std::map<int, Pregunta>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const int, Pregunta> >}’)                         In this line  -> i.it = preguntas.begin();

Comment: Finally I have found my mistake, I had to use class const_iterator{ private:  map<int,Pregunta>::const_iterator it, before I wrote iterator intead of const_iterator. Also I have to use const to *it.

Answer (score 1):

Your cbegin and cend should be const:

```
const_iterator cbegin() const {
//                      ^^^^^
    const_iterator i ; 
    i.it = preguntas.begin();
    return i ;
}

const_iterator cend() const {
//                    ^^^^^
    const_iterator i;
    i.it= preguntas.end();
    return i;
}
```

That said, instead of defining iterator and const_iterator, you can just import them from the map:

```
class ConjuntoPreguntas {
private:
    map<int,Pregunta> preguntas;

public:
    using const_iterator = map<int,Pregunta>::const_iterator;
    using iterator = map<int,Pregunta>::iterator;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tryed to compile with const and without const, but the error compiler it's the same : error: no match for ‘operator=’

Comment: If I compile with out write const, my class compile perfecly, but the imprimir function in main class has a mistake, and If I try to compile using const my class doesn't compile.